# where can I find shapefiles for the highways of Puerto Rico?

Tags: data-request, usa, geospatial

I am looking for the shapefiles of the intersetate highways of Puerto Rico in an easy to use geoJSON format.  I found this page here http://www.baruch.cuny.edu/geoportal/data/esri/esri_usa.htm  but when I unpacked could only find 50 states.

Even though PR is an island, there are 3 interstates.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since I have promised, I will answer this question without waiting for its migration, if it will ever happen. Basically, I think that the **best and latest data set** that you can find now is [this one](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset/tiger-line-shapefile-2013-state-puerto-rico-primary-and-secondary-roads-state-based-shapefile) - from the US official open data repository's TIGER/Line database. [This page](http://catalog.data.gov/dataset?q=%22Interstate+Highways%22&sort=score+desc%2C+name+asc&metadata_type=geospatial&ext_location=Puerto+Rico&ext_bbox=-67.942726%2C17.926405%2C-65.242737%2C18.520166&ext_prev_extent=) is generated, based on a relevant search (Puerto Rico), and might also contain some data sets of your interest.

Other potentially useful data sets include ones within [U.S. Atlas TopoJSON repository](https://github.com/mbostock/us-atlas) (on how to use the data via `R`, see [this nice tutorial](https://stat.duke.edu/~cr173/Sta523_Fa14/shapefiles.html)) as well as [this repository](https://github.com/jalbertbowden/us-data/tree/master/shapefiles/us-mjrrds) of U.S. major roads ESRI shapefile and geoJSON data sets (you have to check whether this repository contains PR data).

Comment: It had all 50 states and US territories, and I was able to extract those pertaining to Puerto Rico.  Thanks!

Comment: @johnmangual: Excellent! I'm very glad to be able to help out. You're quite welcome!